# subtracting integer python weird results

Tags: python

basically what I'm doing is downloading some date from a website using urllib. That number comes to be in what I believe is Byte form. So I change it to an integer by doing the following. This seems to work fine.

```
real_value = (int(real_value) / 100)
```

Then I create another variable which should equal the difference between two values.

```
add_to_value = real_value - last_real_value
print(add_to_value)
```

The weird thing is, this sometimes works and other times I get results with a lot of extra digits on the end or it will say "9.999999999999996e-05".

So I'm really confused. Any ideas?

Comment: Floating point error: see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The weired values are normal and should be correct.

This is because you are using floating point arithmetic. You can always limit the precision of the results, by, e.g., setting the number of digits that are used for the representation.

Refer to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Comment: This ended up working for my purpose. I think I could have also used the decimal module but using the below precision works for me.
    print ("%0.4f" %real_value)

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point numbers [can't represent most numbers exactly](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). Even with a very simple example:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.1
0.20000000000000001
```

You can see it's not exact. If you use floating-point numbers, this is just something you'll have to deal with. Alternatively, you can use [Python's `decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('0.1') + Decimal('0.1')
Decimal('0.2')
```

Even `decimal` can't represent every number exactly, but it should give you much more reasonable results when dealing with lots of base-10 operations.

Answer (score 0):

read up on [issues with floating points in python](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

assuming you are yousing python3: you may want to use a double `/` for classic python2's 'integer division' behaviour where the result gets rounded.

```
real_value = (int(real_value) // 100)
```